# voltar versão do plugin woocomerc 3.7.0 para 3.6.5

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Olá, Aparentemente a nova versão da API woocomerc n aceita mais URL de cadastro de imagens com "?" então minha api de cadastro de produto pro ERP para os sites wordpress não estão cadastro imagens da erro de "woocommerce_product_invalid_image_id", antes deu um outro erro de "woocommerce_product_image_upload_error" mas adicionei no arquivo wp-config.php

```
define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true);
```

essa URL imagem funciona e todas tem extensão .jpg (na nova versão se n tiver extensão da o mesmo erro) :

"https://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/5718897981_10faa45ac3_b-640x624.jpg"

no meu caso eu mando as imagens acessando meu banco de dados no momento de execução do java.

essa e minha url da imagem que passo na requisição de cadastro
"http://HOST.com.br/wicket/fotosprodutos?idObj=8XX&idAdm=X7&nomeArquivo=1fXXXX-baba-ff217e38d3e6.jpg"

antes funcionava agora com esse "?" onde passo os parâmetros depois a api não aceita mais.

então quero saber se eu voltando a versão do plugins vou perder tudo que tenho cadastro no Wordpress para poder instalar uma versão mais antiga do plugin a 3.6.5 pelo menos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As informações do Wordpress não ficam armazenadas no plugin e sim no banco de dados, dessa forma se você realizar o *rollback* do seu plugin não perderá os dados.

Existe um plugin que faz isso, o [WP Rollback](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rollback/), que gerencia as versões de todos os plugins e permite voltar às versões anteriores facilmente.

Comment: estou fazendo backup para usar o plugin wptimecapsule e dou o feedback

Comment: voltei para versão do woocomerc Versão 3.4.7 na qual e uma antes de lançar a api v3 e deu certo. rum que uma coluna do pedido de venda bugou tive que volta no banco